How do I replicate the exact animation done on flecto.io hero section
I came across https://flecto.io(use a vpn if the site doesn't open) and the site caught my attention. I want to replicate the animation in the hero section. To be more precise, that is the part where the green rectangle turned into a cross-like shape.
Starting shape

Final Shape (I removed unwanted distractions)

I understand that this could be done with the use of gsap morphSVG plugin. But I am finding the use of that plugin for this purpose to be difficult. Here is a link to the demo I am working on Here.
HTML
<div class="container">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1900 1500" fill="none">
      <g>
        <path id="rectangle" d="M0 0H1889V157V758V915H0V758V178.5V0Z" fill="black"/>
       
         <path id="final-stage" class="hide" d="M505.5 125.5H22.5H19C9.05887 125.5 1 133.559 1 143.5V774C1 783.941 9.05887 792 19 792H198.5C208.441 792 216.5 800.059 216.5 810V898C216.5 907.941 224.559 916 234.5 916H1426.5C1436.44 916 1444.5 907.941 1444.5 898V809.5C1444.5 799.559 1452.56 791.5 1462.5 791.5H1872C1881.94 791.5 1890 783.441 1890 773.5V144C1890 134.059 1881.94 126 1872 126H1385.5C1375.56 126 1367.5 117.941 1367.5 108V19C1367.5 9.05887 1359.44 1 1349.5 1H541.5C531.559 1 523.5 9.05888 523.5 19V107.5C523.5 117.441 515.441 125.5 505.5 125.5Z" fill="black" stroke="black" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>

CSS
.container {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  visibility: hidden;
}

Javascript (I am using gsap plugin, and gsap morphSVG plugin on codepen)
gsap.registerPlugin(MorphSVGPlugin);

// MorphSVGPlugin.defaultType = "rotational";

var tl = gsap.timeline();
const rectangle = document.getElementById("rectangle");

  tl.to(rectangle, { duration: 1, morphSVG: {shape: "#final-stage", shapeIndex: -2 }});

This was my result https://streamable.com/mnh46o (this content might not be available in the future)
The thing is that after inspecting the site, the creators didn't morph a rectangle into a cross. They broke down their shape into smaller forms, consisting of two frames with different builds.

Notice that the first frame is a solid shape that has a cut out of a cross, while the second is a combination of several shapes that form the cut out of a cross. Why did they build the hero section this way? I am yet to figure it out. But I believe that this method is what makes their animation smoother than my method of morphing an SVG into a cross.
So, what do you all think? How can I replicate this design? What is the best method to do this?

The Solution
I finally got to understand the problem and here is the breakdown of my solution. Thanks to @chrwahi answer I was able to understand how to get around this.
The problem
The problem was animating from one SVG to another. When thinking of animations between SVGs you need to consider the commands used in creating each SVG. Transaction from the green rectangle to the green cross was messy for me initially because I was animating a rectangle of lesser commands than the cross.

That was why the animation was so buggy.
The Fix
By using the SVG Editor you can see all the commands for the path for both the cross and the rectangle.

After playing with the editor I began to understand what @chrwahi did. He used the used the cross commands to form the rectangle.

Notice that this is a rectangle but the commands are similar to the cross. Also notice that the exact values for some of the commands are different for the rectangle. By adjusting the command value to make the SVG look like a rectangle you can then have a suitable SVG that can be animated smoothly from a rectangle to a cross.
This means the cross has 27 commands(read about the d attribute and the commands here) and the rectangle was built to match the 27 commands. So by adjusting the 27 commands of the cross to form a rectangle, you can smoothly animate the rectangle into a cross. That's the secret!
Note
You might need to play around with this approach to get a floorless animation. But this idea should put you on the right track.
Check out the final result on codepen (Make sure to use the left/right view and not the top/bottom view by changing the layout)
    // Please view the final result on codepen. I can't add a codepen link without adding codes. But this solution is not to showcase the code but to explain the idea.


You need two paths; the starting and ending path. The animation can either be done using CSS animations or with SVG animation with SMIL.
In you code there are 27 commands in the ending path, so you should have the same number of commands in the starting path.
Here, I have created a "crude" version where the starting path is just a square, the commands are relative, and most of the commands just have zeros. In a production ready version you would match all the commands so that they move in the right way and also maintain the rounded corners.


path {
  d: path('m 1 1 h 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 915 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 1889 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v -915 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h -1889 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 z');
  animation-duration: 3s;
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    d: path('m 1 1 h 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 915 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 1889 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v -915 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 h -1889 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 v 0 c 0 0 0 0 0 0 z');
  }
  to {
    d: path('M505.5 125.5H22.5H19C9.05887 125.5 1 133.559 1 143.5V774C1 783.941 9.05887 792 19 792H198.5C208.441 792 216.5 800.059 216.5 810V898C216.5 907.941 224.559 916 234.5 916H1426.5C1436.44 916 1444.5 907.941 1444.5 898V809.5C1444.5 799.559 1452.56 791.5 1462.5 791.5H1872C1881.94 791.5 1890 783.441 1890 773.5V144C1890 134.059 1881.94 126 1872 126H1385.5C1375.56 126 1367.5 117.941 1367.5 108V19C1367.5 9.05887 1359.44 1 1349.5 1H541.5C531.559 1 523.5 9.05888 523.5 19V107.5C523.5 117.441 515.441 125.5 505.5 125.5Z');
  }
}
<svg viewBox="0 0 1900 1500">
  <path fill="black" stroke="black"/>
</svg>




This is very nice. Although I do not understand what you mean by commands. You said that I have 27 commands? Are you referring to the points used in forming the SVG? I was able to input your path into my current test and ti worked exactly the way yours worked. So I believe the secret lies in how the path is formed. How do I learn to make the path using the "commands". If I can make the path so that the start and the end matches, I can get better results all the time. Right?

@EtemireEwoma Commands are the points of the path. Read about the d attribute. I often use SvgPathEditor for for creating and editing paths, but there are also others.

@chrwahi I now understand what you meant by commands. For my final question, how do you know how to place the command for both the start and final SVG so that the transition from the start to the final is smooth? I have made several SVGs trying to get the perfect command but the transaction between them is always bad. But you were able to come up with a perfect match between the first and final SVG. How?

@EtemireEwoma I took the original ending path and pasted in into SvgPathEditor. I changed all the commands to relative and changed all the values to zero. I could see that the path went anticlockwise, so I found the v and h commands (vertical and horizontal lines) and changed the value so that I had a square. I took a bit of experimentation, because there are more v and h commands... I will suggest that you start all over, and sketch it out on paper, so that you know how many lines (use l for line) and rounded corners (use c for a curve) you need.

I know that this is my second answer on this question, but I reconsidered the approach after looking more closely at the website that you refer to.
This example is relying on the CSS property mask that can be used for masking an element. The great thing about CSS mask is that it has different properties for size, position etc. So, in the example I have a CSS animation on the mask position and a SVG mask-image that has a path. The basic SVG (top left corner) looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
  <path d="m 200 0 c -8 0 -10 2 -10 10 v 20 c 0 8 -2 10 -10 10
    h -170 c -8 0 -10 2 -10 10 v 50 h 400 v -100 z" fill="black"/>
</svg>

And here in a snippet:


<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 400 100">
  <path d="m 200 0 c -8 0 -10 2 -10 10 v 20 c 0 8 -2 10 -10 10
    h -170 c -8 0 -10 2 -10 10 v 50 h 400 v -100 z" fill="black"/>
</svg>



The full example looks like this:


body {
  height: 200vh;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 200px auto 200px;
  height: calc(100vh - 1em);
  padding: .5em;
}

.cell {
  padding: 10px;
}

.topleft {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.topmiddle {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.topright {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.topmiddle:before {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  content: "";
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0MDAgMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtIDIwMCAwIGMgLTggMCAtMTAgMiAtMTAgMTAgdiAyMCBjIDAgOCAtMiAxMCAtMTAgMTAgaCAtMTcwIGMgLTggMCAtMTAgMiAtMTAgMTAgdiA1MCBoIDQwMCB2IC0xMDAgeiIgZmlsbD0iYmxhY2siLz4KPC9zdmc+');
  mask-size: 400px;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: -200px -50px;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: topleft;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.topmiddle:after {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  content: "";
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0MDAgMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtIDIwMCAwIGMgOCAwIDEwIDIgMTAgMTAgdiAyMCBjIDAgOCAyIDEwIDEwIDEwIGggMTcwIGMgOCAwIDEwIDIgMTAgMTAgdiA1MCBoIC00MDAgdiAtMTAwIHoiIGZpbGw9ImJsYWNrIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  mask-size: 400px;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: 0px -50px;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: topright;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  border-radius: 0 10px 0 0;
}

@keyframes topleft {
  from {
    mask-position: -200px -50px;
  }
  to {
    mask-position: 0px 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes topright {
  from {
    mask-position: 0px -50px;
  }
  to {
    mask-position: -200px 0px;
  }
}

.fullmiddle {
  grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  grid-row: 2;
  background-color: SeaGreen;
}

.bottomleft {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.bottommiddle {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  position: relative;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.bottomright {
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 3;
}

.bottommiddle:before {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -200px;
  content: "";
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0MDAgMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtIDIwMCAxMDAgYyAtOCAwIC0xMCAtMiAtMTAgLTEwIHYgLTIwIGMgMCAtOCAtMiAtMTAgLTEwIC0xMCBoIC0xNzAgYyAtOCAwIC0xMCAtMiAtMTAgLTEwIHYgLTUwIGggNDAwIHYgMTAwIHoiIGZpbGw9ImJsYWNrIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  mask-size: 400px;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: -200px -50px;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: bottomleft;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.bottommiddle:after {
  background-color: SeaGreen;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -200px;
  content: "";
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4KPHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCA0MDAgMTAwIj4KICA8cGF0aCBkPSJtIDIwMCAxMDAgYyA4IDAgMTAgLTIgMTAgLTEwIHYgLTIwIGMgMCAtOCAyIC0xMCAxMCAtMTAgaCAxNzAgYyA4IDAgMTAgLTIgMTAgLTEwIHYgLTUwIGggLTQwMCB2IDEwMCB6IiBmaWxsPSJibGFjayIvPgo8L3N2Zz4=');
  mask-size: 400px;
  mask-repeat: no-repeat;
  mask-position: 0px 0px;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: bottomright;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  border-radius: 0 0 10px 0;
}

@keyframes bottomleft {
  from {
    mask-position: -200px -50px;
  }
  to {
    mask-position: 0px -50px;
  }
}

@keyframes bottomright {
  from {
    mask-position: 0px 0px;
  }
  to {
    mask-position: -200px -50px;
  }
}
<section>
  <div class="cell topleft">topleft</div>
  <div class="cell topright">topright</div>
  <div class="cell topmiddle">topmiddle</div>
  <div class="cell fullmiddle">
    <p>fullmiddle</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell bottomleft">bottomleft</div>
  <div class="cell bottomright">bottomright</div>
  <div class="cell bottommiddle">bottommiddle</div>
</section>




This is also very nice. Although I prefer the first option because of customisation. I instead used it with gsap morphSVG and it's working well. My plan also involve me doing similar transitions between other SVGs. Thank you
